# android: start in symbol keyboard mode, but don't restrict to numbers-only input

Tags: java, android

I want to specify that Android should start the soft keyboard for a given EditText in the numeric/symbols mode. I know this can be done by setting the input type of the EditText to be numeric using EditText.setInputType() except that I do not want to restrict the input type for the EditText to numeric input only**. Is there another way to tell Android what keyboard it should open for a given EditText?

** I want essentially a Math class of numeric input, accepting arbitrary mathematical expressions, including [0,9.+-/*()@:].

Comment: Almost the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219855/how-to-show-android-keyboard-with-symbols-mode-by-default

Answer (score -2):

After some research and trying lots of different things, I found the answer:

```
editField.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
//           ^^^ note the Raw!
```

So you need the **Raw** version of setting the input type to circumvent a KeyListener being set, which restricts the input.

Comment: SetInputType & SetRawInputType restricts input which the question specifically stated they did not want to do

Answer (score -3):

I believe the magic is in:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this makes the input accept only digits. I'll verify, though.

Comment: SetInputType & SetRawInputType restricts input which the question specifically stated they did not want to do.