# Android keyboard for bank account entry [0-9-xX]

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I need a editText input type that allows me to increase the experience of the user when he/she is entering a bank account or bank branch. The numbers should follow those rules:

Account: \d{1,5}-\d{1,2}|X --> one to five numeric digits, dash, one or two numeric digits or one X character

Branch: \d{1,5}(-\d{1,2}|-X)? --> one to five numeric digits, dash, zero, one or two numeric digits or one X character

As my entry have likely more numeric digits I want the keyboard to offer numbers primarily, and if the user have a X digit he/she can swap the input type. Basically I want a keyboard whose symbolic layout is displayed first.

**UPDATE:**

I tried changing the input type in the edit text xml:

```
<EditText
    style="@style/Subhead.Form"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLength="7"
    app:hint="@{@string/profile_hint_bankBranch}"
    app:bindTo="@{viewModel.branch.input}"
    tools:text="1234-5"/>
```

But this presents the text layout first, as expected, I also tried several other options but I think that none does what I want.

In iOS I'm using the "Numbers and punctuation" keyboard type, that does exactly what I want, is there any easy solution to have the same behaviour?

Comment: Please show the code you've tried to implement this, and state specifically where you are getting stuck.

Comment: I updated with my xml file, I tried this guy's solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/29175373/1080583 but I dont want something so fancy, just presenting the symbolic keyboard as default would be fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "phone" inputType on your edittext. This will reduce the keyboard to numbers and dashes. http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html

For more fancy stuff (regex-check, autocomplete, changing keyboard style) you will have to resort to something like a custom text change listener.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)

Comment: Just numbers and dashes are not sufficient, I also need the X character, the phone input type have letters on the number keys but I did not manage to access them as type options